# How to improve conditional tensor operation

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have conditional operation of tensors, such as

```
for i:
   if check(rate[i]):
      rate[i] = reset(rate[i])
```

right now, i implemented as following,

```
rate = torch.where(check(rate), reset(rate), rate)
```

It turns out that even for tensor where check(rate) is false, reset(rate) is still operated, kind of like

```
new_rate = reset(rate)
rate = torch.where(check(rate), new_rate, rate)
```

I am wondering anyway i could improve the performance here, if reset(rate) is very expensive

Updated

I've tried mask method, like following,

```
import torch
import time
import copy

def reset(t):
    return 1.0 / torch.log(1.0 + t)

source1 = torch.FloatTensor(10000, 10000)
source1.uniform_()
source2 = copy.deepcopy(source1)

start = time.time()
mask = source1 < 0.5
source1[mask] = reset(source1[mask])
print('test1 takes: ', time.time() - start)

start = time.time()
mask = source2 < 0.5
source2 = torch.where(mask, reset(source2), source2)
print('test2 takes: ', time.time() - start)
```

On my machine, it shows,

test1 takes:  3.455298900604248

test2 takes:  1.8106980323791504

Any way i could improve it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behavior is pretty straightforward and actually comes from python, not pytorch: when you pass in a function call into another function, the function call will be executed before you pass it in. That means that for your example, reset(rate) will be fully executed.

To get around that, you might want to look into masking. Pytorch is quite efficient here!

The general paradigm would be:

```
mask = check(rate)
rate[mask] = reset(rate[mask])
```

The idea is that you compute a `torch.bool` or `torch.byte` mask (so the function `check` would need to return such a tensor) of the same size as your target tensor. Then, the same python behavior works in your favor, as `rate[mask]` will select only the relevant items first, and then apply the `reset` function.

Comment: I did try masking way, but it seems that masking will reshape the tensor and make it even slower. not sure it is due to the high dimenson of rate tensor here.

Comment: Hey - can you offer some more specifics to your question? Masking is oftentimes much faster. If it is not, I need more details :-)

Comment: I did lots of tests, and do see that due to less operation of mask method, the performance on CPU is better, but on GPU the performance is much worse due to tensor matrix reshape and GPU efficiency is much lower